# How can I do generic this method

Tags: c#, winforms

> `ListControlConvertEventArgs` and sender return object my class so which type I don't know for this reason I couldn't generic

```
  private void cmb_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            string Name = ((Director)e.ListItem).Name;
            string LastName = ((Director)e.ListItem).SurName;
            e.Value = Name + " " + LastName;
        }

        private void cmbActors_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            string Name = ((Actor)e.ListItem).Name;
            string LastName = ((Actor)e.ListItem).SurName;
            e.Value = Name + " " + LastName;
        }
```

Comment: WinForms does not support generic `sender` parameters, they must be typed as `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change event handler signature, but you can introduce an abstraction to represent names and cast `ListItem` to the abstraction to access common properties.

```
public interface INames
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string SurName { get; set; }
}

// Implement INames in the classes you are using in ListControl
public class Director : INames { }
public class Actor : INames { }

private void cmb_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (INames)e.ListItem;
    e.Value = $"{item.Name} {item.SurName}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Actor` and `Director` types will need a common interface or base-class:

```
interface IPerson
{
    String Name    { get; }
    String SurName { get; }
}

class Director : IPerson { ... }
class Actor    : IPerson { ... }
```

Then you can do this:

```
private void OnPersonComboboxFormat( ComboBox cmd, ListControlConvertEventArgs e )
{
    IPerson person = (IPerson)e.ListItem;
    e.Value = person.Name + " " + person.LastName;
}
```

But you can't use this as the event-handler directly - you still need match the `ListControlConvertEventHandler` delegate:

```
private void OnPersonComboboxFormat( Object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e )
{
    if( sender == this.cmb || sender == this.cmbActors )
    {
        OnPersonComboboxFormat( (ComboBox)sender, e );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dai . I already have given inheritance PersonEntity my classes, I will use this code ,  Thank Yoı private void cmb_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            string Name = ((PersonEntity)e.ListItem).Name;
            string LastName = ((PersonEntity)e.ListItem).SurName;
            e.Value = Name + " " + LastName;
        }

Answer (score 0):

@Dai is right. But you can avoid code duplication in the following fashion.

Create a separate private method like this:

```
private void CombineFirstAndLastname<TRole>(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
    where TRole : IFullname
{
    var role = (TRole)e.ListItem;
    e.Value = $"{role.Name} {role.LastName}"
}

public interface IFullname
{
    string Name { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}

public class Director : IFullname
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Actor : IFullname
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

this method can be called like this;

```
private void cmb_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    CombineFirstAndLastname<Director>(sender, e);
}

private void cmbActors_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    CombineFirstAndLastname<Actor>(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: This works without needing the generic type parameter - just cast directly to `IFullName`.